# Prolog: Coming up with Herbrand Universe and Herbrand Base

Tags: prolog

I have serious problems to understand the concept of Prolog and the corresponding Herbrand Universe, Herbrand Base and so on.
For example if I have a Prolog program:

```
p(X,Y) :- q(X,Y), q(Y,X).
s(a).
s(b).
s(c).
q(a,b).
q(b,a).
q(a,c).
```

I mean - I know what the Prolog program is supposed to do, but I cannot come up with the corresponding Herbrand Universe or Herbrand Base.

For the Herbrand Universe I have to search all variable-free constructor terms.

1. What are constructors in this context?
2. I would simply guess that `HU = {a,b,c, s(a), s(b), s(c), q(a,a), q(a,b), q(b,a)... p(a,a), p(a,b), ... s(s(a))....}`
3. How to come up with the Herbrand Base?

I'm sorry for all the questions, but I think I'm mixing so many different "Herbrand" things up :-(.

Can anyone help me and explain things to me?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Herbrand+Base)?

Comment: Of course. But I simply don't get the point :-(. I spend so many hours on this and still have the feeling that I understand nothing.
e.G. Is there one Herbrand Universe for the whole Prolog program or are there several ones - one for each predicate (or constructor?)...

Comment: @false I personally can't understand that Wikipedia page either.

Comment: @WillNess: [This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerbrandBase.html), too?

Comment: @WillNess: HB: take all predicates and fill their arguments with HU terms.

Comment: @false OK, thanks. though it seems to contradict the line in the WMW directly above that, which seems to imply only `p...` to be used for the base with the HU terms, as it is the only one that contains variables. Others (`s..., q...`) could conceivably be used as they are given (already ground).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_algebra), "a Herbrand universe ... is defined starting from the set of constants and function symbols in a set of clauses."

So if we follow this definition, here it would consist of atoms `a, b, c` and compound terms with functors `s/1, q/2, p/2` and arguments which are in the Herbrand universe themselves:

```
hu(a).
hu(b).
hu(c).
hu(s(Y)):- hu(Y).
hu(q(Y,Z)):- hu(Y), hu(Z).
hu(p(Y,Z)):- hu(Y), hu(Z).
```

"The set of all ground atoms that can be formed from predicate symbols from S and terms from  H is called the [Herbrand base](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerbrandUniverse.html)":

```
hb(s(Y)):- hu(Y).
hb(q(Y,Z)):- hu(Y), hu(Z).
hb(p(Y,Z)):- hu(Y), hu(Z).
```